# Is there a way to "outsource" yield statements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, generator

To give you an idea what I'm trying to do:
As someone who teaches sorting algorithms, I'd like to enable students to easily visualize how their sorting algorithms work and found generators to be realy useful for that, sice I can interrupt the execution at any point: The following code that a student could write can be turned into an animation by my library:

```
function* bubbleSort(arr){
    let done = false;
    while(!done){
        done = true;
        for(let i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
            yield {type:"comparison",indexes:[i-1,i]};
            if(arr[i-1]>arr[i]){
                yield {type:"swap",indexes:[i-1,i]};
                swap(arr,i-1,i);
                done = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return "sorted";
}
```

This works quite well, but it would be a lot better, if I could write functions `compare(i,j)` and `swap(i,j)` that handle the yield internally (and in case of compare also return a boolean value). So I'd like to be able to express the above as:

```
function* bubbleSort(arr){
    let done = false;
    while(!done){
        done = true;
        for(let i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(compare(i-1,i)){
                swap(arr,i-1,i);
                done = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return "sorted";
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do

```
 if(yield* compare(i-1,i))
```

Which will pass the `yield` calls inside of `compare` to the outside.

Comment: `yield*` seems to work nicely for `swap()`-function that needs no return value, but how would `compare` need to be constructed to make your statement work?

Comment: @anton it works as expected just `return true;` from `compare` and it will enter the if branch

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it :)

Comment: @anton glad to help :)